# The object a pointer is pointing to changes values every time a get function is called? C++

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers

I have two classes, one for fuel and the other for miles. Every 24 miles you use 1 fuel. For this assignment I am required to have a pointer in my "miles" class to point to a "fuel" class so we can have "mile" class work with the "fuel" class without having to create a whole object "fuel" object inside the "mile" class. It was going well until I tested it and after some debugs it seems that, for some reason, the fuel object has it's values changed whenever I call the get function in my "miles" class. However, all I am doing is returning a member variable. Why would it change my fuel object? I also do not change the pointer's value anywhere else so it should always point to the fuel object.

***Class Specification***

```
#ifndef ODO_H
#define ODO_H

#include "FuelGauge.h"

class Odometer
{
private:
    int currentMiles = 0;
    int maxMilage = 999999;
    FuelGauge* fuelObject = nullptr;
    int counter = 0;

public:
    Odometer(int, FuelGauge);

    int getMiles();

    void addMiles();
};

#endif ODO_H
```

***Class Implementation***

```
#include "Odometer.h"

Odometer::Odometer(int currMileage, FuelGauge Gauge) {
    if (currMileage >= 0 && currMileage <= maxMilage) {
        currentMiles = currMileage;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Starting mileage is invalid" << endl;
    }

    fuelObject = &Gauge;
}

int Odometer::getMiles() {
    return currentMiles;
}

void Odometer::addMiles() {
    if (currentMiles < maxMilage) {
        currentMiles++;
        counter++;
    }
    else if (currentMiles >= maxMilage) {
        cout << "You have reached the max mileage ... resetting to zero!" << endl;
        currentMiles = 0;
    }

    if (counter >= 24) {
        fuelObject->useFuel();
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

In main, when I call the getMiles() function; The object pointed to by "fuelObject" has it's values changed to some random large number. Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you create a smaller object that just manipulates that value and nothing else? Also, in some(obvious) cases one would be getting back the address of the object or a random cell of memory when the return is some large random int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be undefined behavior right here.

```
Odometer::Odometer(int currMileage, FuelGauge Gauge) {
    if (currMileage >= 0 && currMileage <= maxMilage) {
        currentMiles = currMileage;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Starting mileage is invalid" << endl;
    }

    fuelObject = &Gauge;
}
```

Once your constructor finishes execution, your `fuelObject` is left pointing to garbage, since the parameter will go out of scope and it is by-val.

Apart from that, I have to agree with @scheff that the error you are seeing is likely not caused by the code you have shown.

Comment: Passing `FuelGauge Gauge` by value - how could I miss this... ;-)

Comment: Don't talk to me about missing things when reviewing something. :D I have _tales_ to tell, sans various NDAs which apply.

Comment: Thanks so much ;-;. Turns out nothing else was wrong only what you said. I just changed how I constructed the odometer class by passing in the address of the fuel class instead of the class object itself!

Comment: Good for you! However, I recommend you switch to using a `std::shared_ptr<T>` for shared ownership rather than working with raw pointers. You can read about it further [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).